# String Constraint Relation Doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, constrained-dynamics

consider the diagram i have attached for reference guys.
so in the diagram, the author has taken all the length of the strings from some single datum, the ceiling here.
my question is, if i take the length of the strings as i have shown in the second diagram, i get a relation Yb + Yc = constant => Vb = -Vc which is a totally different relation!!

could someone explain why this is incorrect?
in general, do i always take all the string lengths from some datum?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the datum from which you measure Yb and Yc moves. So those velocities Vb and Vc are measured relative the the axle of the large pulley wheel which moves relative to the ceiling.  In the book derivation all the velocities are relative to the fixed "ceiling".

Comment: aaah i just didn't consider THAT!